# Fatal error: Call to a member function getWelcome() on boolean

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I get

> php fatal error: Call to a member function getWelcome() on boolean in
>   /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/domain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Welcome.php
>   on line 43.

How to solve this error in Magento 1.7?

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Welcome extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    /**
     * Get block messsage
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
                return Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('header')->getWelcome();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you post the relevant code from your Welcome.php file?

Comment: i have added relevant code .please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check http://freegento.com/doc/d7/d92/class_mage___core___model___layout.html#4c2f3ed0733b1d16c6b9d1d13898574f

When the block can't be found, the `getBlock` returns `false` instead of an object, and the error is thrown when you try to call `getWelcome` on this.

(definition of getBlock in case the link doesn't work):

```
{
         if (isset($this->_blocks[$name])) {
             return $this->_blocks[$name];
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     }
```

Add an `if` statement to check if the block exists before trying to operate on it.

Comment: i have checked block returning false .what should i do to correct it and also please see this related question i asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401533/mageapp-getlayout-getblockheader-returning-false-in-magento-1-7?noredirect=1#comment105010556_59401533