# Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('header') returning false in magento 1,7

Tags: php, magento-1.7

In welcome.php file of magento 1.7

`Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('header')->getWelcome(); getBlock('header')` returning false 
please check code sample.

```
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if (isset($this->_blocks[$name])) {
            echo $this->_blocks[$name];
        } else {
            return Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('header')->getWelcome();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want to ask , in this code  (isset($this->_blocks[$name])) always returning false . so   how to get block in magento 1.7 .please see this ,i have asked another question related to this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59399906/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getwelcome-on-boolean/59400363#59400363